# How to route between two different action methods with same parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing ASP.NET Web API 2 with Attribute Routing.
I have a controller class and two action methods in it:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/settings")]
    public class SettingsController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("{getVersion}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDBVersion(string PlatformID)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                SqlManager sqlManager = new SqlManager();
                DataTable dt = sqlManager.GetLocalDBVersion(PlatformID);

                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return Ok(serializer.Serialize(rows));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, ex.Message);
            }
        }
        [Route("getBookingSetting/{PlatformID:int}")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDBBookingSetting(int PlatformID)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                SqlManager sqlManager = new SqlManager();
                DataTable dt = sqlManager.GetBookingSetting(PlatformID.ToString());

                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return Ok(serializer.Serialize(rows));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

i am calling the first action method by url:

```
/api/settings/getVersion?PlatformID=1
```

and second one by:

```
/api/settings/getBookingSetting?PlatformID=1
```

however in both cases, the first action method gets called everytime.
How can i route between such cases where method names are different but parameters are of same name and type(or of different types)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your route definitions do not match your URLs:

```
[Route("{getVersion}")]
```

This expects a route parameter "getVersion", so even URLs like `/api/settings/1` will match. You should rewrite it so that it's not a parameter:

```
[Route("getVersion")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDBVersion([FromUri]string PlatformID)
```

Next:

```
[Route("getBookingSetting/{PlatformID:int}")]
```

This definition expects `PlatformID` as part of the route (i.e. `/api/settings/getBookingSetting/1`), but you're passing it as a query string.

You should change the definition to this:

```
[Route("getBookingSetting")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetDBBookingSetting([FromUri]int PlatformID)
```

Comment: When i change it according to your suggested format, it gives me this error: 'Multiple actions were found that match the request'

Comment: yes, this is the complete code block, i have just changed the route as you commented above,, but after this, it gives this multiple actions exception

Comment: OK, but the only two actions in the controller have different routes, so it can't be those. You don't have two with the same `Route(...)` do you?

Comment: no, i have only these two action methods in my controller, and the exception message says that 'Multiple actions were found that match the request: GetDBVersion' that means url is always mapping to the first action method.. m i right?

Comment: Can you send me a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) link with the code as it currently is? Something sounds very strange. I can't reproduce it at my end by placing the amended code into a new controller in a new project.

Comment: @UsmanFarooq My answer clearly demonstrated that a string surrounded by curly braces (e.g. `{variable}`) in a route represents route parameters which will be mapped to method parameters. What you've done, is taken the routes I proposed and added curly braces to them, so now BOTH routes evaluate to `/api/settings`. Please correct this and it will work.